# Custom global exception & error handler in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

What is the correct way to assign a controller action or middleware to handle all exceptions (globally) and strict parameter errors in Rails 4?

Keep in mind, I don't want to do it just for one controller.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious solution is the application controller (`/app/controllers/application_controller.rb`), should work fine if your controllers have the 7 INCSEUD actions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exceptions_app`.

**application.rb**

```
class Application < Rails::Application
   ...
   config.exceptions_app = lambda do |env|
        ExceptionController.action(:render_error).call(env)
   end
   ...
end
```

**exception_controller.rb**

```
class ExceptionController < ActionController::Base
    layout 'application'

    def render_error
        @exception = env["action_dispatch.exception"]
        @status_code = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
        render :error_page, status: @status_code, layout: true
    end
end
```

Taken from [Rails 3.2 error handling with exceptions_app (Example)](https://coderwall.com/p/w3ghqq/rails-3-2-error-handling-with-exceptions_app)